# How can i in ionic make $state.go move to other view without transition animation?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Well I have a side menu based  ionic application.

The default animation for any view transition is slide right to left; but for few views i need the animation of transition to be none (no animation)

i kind of not able to get how to do that on any documentation at all

Comment: You may try to add the animation class on the ion-view tag of the page you are trying to load

Answer (score 18, accepted):

well i got my answer for ionic IRC  channel

it seams few things changed in version 1.0 beta 14 of ionic

so the way they told that worked perfectly with me is by adding options for the next view using $ionicHistory provider which is available in beta14 only now and hopefully will continue for next versions

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
              disableAnimate: true,
              disableBack: true
            });
```

then we can call $state.go